# Which scripture is the source of this mantra- "Achyutananda Govindaya Namaha"?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, krishna, mantras, identification-request

Which scripture contains the following mantra?:

> Achyutananda Govindaya Namah

Who is the author of this particular scripture? Where can I download this scripture?

Comment: Is it Achyutananta or Achyutananda? Because the three names Achyuta, Ananta, Govinda come in a series in achamana. There might be a relation with it.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It is Achutananda. I also have one more information about this mantra that this mantra is created by Shaunak rishi.